# Cron parameter in not working in sidekiq rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq, sidetiq

I have been implemented **sidekiq-cron** in my rails application. I want to run scheduled task using this gem.

Here is yml file config/schedule.yml :

```yaml
message_worker:
  class: MessageWorker
  queue: default
  cron: "* * * * * *"
```

Here is my worker class:

```rb
class MessageWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options retry: 2, backtrace: true
  def perform()
    # Here is my business logic
  end
end
```

Here I loading all my task in initializer file:

```rb
require 'sidekiq'
require 'sidekiq-cron'
require 'sidekiq/web'

redis_config = YAML.load_file("config/redis.yml")
redis_config.merge! redis_config.fetch(Rails.env, {})
redis_config.symbolize_keys!

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: "redis://localhost:6379/" }
  puts "redis started"
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: "redis://localhost:6379/" }
  puts "configure client"
end
schedule_file = "config/schedule.yml"

if File.exists?(schedule_file) && Sidekiq.server?
 sidekiq_cron = YAML.load_file(schedule_file)
 Sidekiq::Cron::Job.load_from_hash sidekiq_cron
end
```

When I run sidekiq server using bundle ex sedikiq it throws me below exception:

```
2016-12-01T14:08:36.916Z 12150 TID-orgj0i010 ERROR: CRON JOB: can't convert Rufus::Scheduler::ZoTime into an exact number
2016-12-01T14:08:36.916Z 12150 TID-orgj0i010 ERROR: CRON JOB: /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@<gemset-name>/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb:233:in `-'
```

How Can I resolve this problem?

Comment: sidekiq-cron has the dependency rufus-scheduler and problem with sidekiq version. by changing rufus-scheduler version to 3.2.2 this will work for me.
Just added this line in my gemfile :  gem 'rufus-scheduler', '3.2.2'

Comment: Your comment should be an answer!